# Php Sessions and Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

Within my index.php file I have an AJAX function that will call a function within another php file which should increment a number and return it whenever i call the AJAX function.

The problem is that the number never changes. I have tried lots of different things. Too many to list them all unfortunately.

My index.php file.

```
<?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
 ?>
 <?php include 'blogFunction.php';?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function doSomething()
 {
    $.ajax({ url: '/blogFunction.php',
     data: {action: 'test'},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
     document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = '';
              document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = output;
                 }
   });
  }
 </script>

 <div class ="blog" id = "blog"></div>
```

my blogFunction.php

```
<?php 
      if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
         $action = $_POST['action'];
         switch($action) {
            case 'test' :  blogreturn();break;
         }
      }

function blogreturn(){

      $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
      echo "THIS number is:" .$_SESSION['views'];
}
 ?>
```

Right now the output is always '1' whenever i hit the button that calls the AJAX function.

Any help appreciated.

Live Code:[here](http://retrovate.co.uk)

Thank you all for the help so far. One problem down, a new problem appears.

Extended Functionality:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
$action = $_POST['action'];

switch($action) {
    case 'test' :  blogreturn();break;
}
```

}

```
function blogreturn(){  
    $request_url = "http://retrovate.tumblr.com/api/read?type=posts";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
    
    $a = $_SESSION['views'];
    $b = $_SESSION['views'] +4;
    echo "A = ".$a;
    echo "B = ".$b;
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
    for ($i = $a; $i <= $b; $i=$i+1) {
            echo '<h2>'.$xml->posts->post[$i]->{'regular-title'}.'</h2>';
            echo '<br>';
            echo $xml->posts->post[$i]->{'regular-body'};
            echo '<br>';
            echo '<br>';
    }    
}
```

The problem that lies here, is, I click my button once at [my site](http://retrovate.co.uk)

and it increments and shows the new content. I click again and it reverts back to 0. If I click the button numerous times fast, it seems to work.  It seems that chrome is having this problem whereas Firefox is not.

Comment: Why are you using vanilla DOM methods to output the result of the AJAX instead of jQuery? `$('#blog').text(output);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the properly working code...
index.php

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['views'] = 0;
 ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" />
    <body>
        <div class ="blog" id = "blog"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Add to the count!" id="call_ajax"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#call_ajax').click(function () {
                $.ajax({ url: '/blogFunction.php',
                    data: {action: 'test'},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function(output) {
                        document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = '';
                        document.getElementById("blog").innerHTML = output;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
</body>
```

blogFunction.php

```
<?php
session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
     $action = $_POST['action'];
     switch($action) {
        case 'test' :  blogreturn();break;
     }
  }

function blogreturn(){
  $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views']+ 1;
  echo "THIS number is:" .$_SESSION['views'];
}
?>
```

Notice that I'm not including blogFunction.php in the index.php file!  That's important.

The other way you had it, you were setting the variable to 0 each time the page loaded, which was how the function was called (if you used the console to call it).

I added a button for you to click to call the function via Ajax (per your conditions in the original question).

Hope that helps!

Comment: This has helped thanks. I have added further functionality in the blogreturn function that has been causing me further trouble. If you can assist I would be grateful.

Comment: You should clean up your code to get the mucky-muck out of the way.  The jQuery library is called in there at least three times that I could see, versions 1.3, 1.3.2 and 1.4.

When I plug your new blogFunction() into my test page, it works fine (until you run out of blog posts).  It looks to me like there's something awry in the php that you haven't posted.

Comment: Yes I agree, been trying many things around the last few days. Lots of code has been left behind. I have added the entire file in now.

Answer (score 2):

Add `session_start();` to blogFunction.php

Comment: Preferably at the start of the script ;)

Comment: Thanks.This solved my initial problem, new problem has since arisen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call session_start () in your blogFunction.php file. It has to be called before any output to the brower. Probably best case would be to call it first in the script.

Answer (score -3):

I think that you should first unset `$_SESSION['views']` and than write again.

```
function blogreturn(){
  $temp = $_SESSION['views'];
  unset($_SESSION['views']);
  $_SESSION['views'] = $temp + 1;
  echo "THIS number is:" .$_SESSION['views'];
}
```

Comment: This did nothing unfortunately.